# scan resteasy resources by package name

Tags: java, rest, configuration, resteasy, web.xml

I'm configuring my resteasy app and need to turn of auto scanning (two jaxrs applications are in the classpath and it breaks at loading)

For that reason I have configured my web.xml as follow:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>
        io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource,
        com.mycompany.resource.ClientResource,
        com.mycompany.resource.AccountResource,
        ... etc
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is there any way in resteasy to scan by package (`com.mycompany.resource.*`) name instead of having to add each resource ? It seems it's possible with jaxrs but not resteasy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear:

> A comma delimited list of fully qualified JAX-RS resource class names you want to register

You could implement this on your own using for instance the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library. Assuming following textfile:

```
com.foo.bar.TestResource
com.foo.baz.*
```

We can read this textfile in the Application class, search for all classes and add it to the Set returned by `getClasses`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public RestApplication(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        classes = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            URI resourcesConfig = servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/resources.txt").toURI();
            List<String> resources = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(resourcesConfig), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            for (String resource : resources) {
                parseResources(resource);
            }
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not add resource classes", ex);
        }
    }

    private void parseResources(String resource) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (!resource.endsWith(".*")) {
            classes.add(Class.forName(resource));
            return;
        }
        String pkg = resource.substring(0, resource.length() - 2);
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(pkg);
        for (Class<?> scannedResource : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class)) {
            classes.add(scannedResource);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

}
```

NOTE: We're only adding resources with a `@Path` annotation on the class level.

Comment: I was hoping for something out of the box but this does the job. Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I`m not expert in jaxrs , but have you checked those below ?

```
resteasy.scan 
resteasy.scan.resources
```