# HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : of full path: RESTEasy

Tags: maven, tomcat, pom.xml, resteasy, web.xml

I have already spent hours on solving the following problem:

I have a Maven Project with the following web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>xy</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

        <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property  -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

My Java class looks as follows:

```
@Path("/file")
public class File 
{   
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(@MultipartForm Multipart form) {}
```

After Project-> Run as -> Run on Server the correct index.jsp is shown.

When I click a button for uploading the file I get the error:

HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /file/upload of full path: http://localhost:8080/Projectname/rest/file/upload

What I aleady did:

- clean project
- update Maven
- Run as -> Maven -> clean install (build sucess)
- delete Tomcat and installed it again
- disabled autoscan and added "File" manually

Furthermore I get warnings that some jars cannot be found on the Tomcat path (/Tomcat8/wtpwebapps/Projectname/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar (No such file or directory - but it is available in the pom.xml and under target->Projectname->WEB-INF->lib)

I use resteasy-jaxrs version 2.2.1.GA

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below points.

1. Try adding the package name in web.xml inorder for rest easy to scan the class files for JAX-RS annotations. Checkout [scan resteasy resources by package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614046/scan-resteasy-resources-by-package-name)
2. Make sure to set the correct Content-Type while calling the REST endpoint. I.e, multipart/form-data